# Getting an `Undefined error: 0` using ifstream::read

Tags: c++11, ifstream

I'm playing a little with `ifstream` on macOS with clang.

I'm trying to read the whole file using the `read` method:

```
  ifstream is(filename);
  is.exceptions(ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit);

  // This set up a buffer with a size of 2048 bytes.
  void *buff = XML_GetBuffer(parser, 2048);

  do {
    is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buff), 2048);
    auto charBuff = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buff);
    std::cout << charBuff << std::endl;
  } while (!is.eof());
  is.close();
```

By processing a long file, an exception is thrown:
`ios_base::clear: unspecified iostream_category error`

I tried to get more information with `strerror(errno)` but I only get :
`Err:Undefined error: 0`

What is wrong with this code ?
How could I get more information about the reason of the failure ?

Comment: unrelated to the question: but I wouldn't check the required condition `!is.eof()` in a `do-while` loop, since you would try to read the stream once, even in case the stream is empty.

Comment: My guess would be, `charBuff` is not NUL-terminated, and `std::cout << charBuff` exhibits undefined behavior by way of walking off the end of the buffer.

Comment: Also, `istream::read` sets `failbit` (in addition to `eofbit`) when fewer bytes are available than requested. You asked the stream to throw an exception when `failbit` is set.

Comment: I does not seems to be related to the size of the buffer. If I reduce the size of the buffer, the code throws the exceptions exactly at the same time. How can I get more informations about the error ?